# php - send email with french accents in subject

Tags: php, email, character-encoding, non-ascii-characters

I am able to send french accent `é` in the body in php mail using the following code:

```
$subject = "é";
$message = "<html>&eacute;<html>";

$headers = 'From: noreply@mymail.fr' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

However, how do I send accents in the subject?

Comment: you want to send only subject content in french language

Comment: @AkhileshSingh No both subject and message. So far, I've only been able to send accents in message.